# Generic Covariance issue

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

I am trying to work out some generic interfaces that includes a Dictionary and the items that it contains, both of which currently look like the code below.

As you can see I punted on the Dictionary, making the value be object. I would ideally like an interface with a covariant KEy of TParentMOdel and a covariant value of TModel, just like the item is, but I haven't been able to work that out so far (not sure its possible either).

What I do have seems to work until I try to add the last item in the last usage example below. The GenderVm is essentially an ISatteliteVm

It *seems* like the problem is with Gender being an Enum, which doesn't fully make sense to me. TParentModel in this case is Person, which is a subclass of Party. Covariance seems to be working here as I can add other items where TParentModel is a Person.

Which is why I say it *seems* like the problem is the value Gender. It's an Enum, and although an Enum is an object I *think* the type constraint system doesn't support Enums.

Is there an easy fix, such as a cast? A  Does anyone see a better way to design SatelliteMap?

Cheers,
Berryl

## Item

```
public interface ISatelliteVm<out TParentModel, out TModel> : ISatelliteVm
{
    TParentModel ParentModel { get; }
    TModel Model { get; }
}
```

## Dictionary

```
public class SatelliteVmMap<TParentModel> : Dictionary<Type, ISatelliteVm<TParentModel, object>>, IEditableObject, IIsDirty
{

    public void Add(ISatelliteVm<TParentModel, object> item) {
        if (item == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("item");
        Add(item.GetType(), item);
    }
}
```

## Usage (abstract class that contains the SatelliteMap)

```
public interface IHubViewModel<out TModel> where TModel : Entity
{

    public void AddSatelliteVm(ISatelliteVm<TModel, object> vm) {
        if (_satelliteVmMap == null) {
            _satelliteVmMap = new SatelliteVmMap<TModel>();
        }
        if (_satelliteVmMap.ContainsKey(vm)) return;

         _satelliteVmMap.Add(vm);
    }
}
```

## Usage (subclass that contains several entries of ISatelliteVm)

```
    public abstract class PartyDetailVm : HubViewModel<Party>
{
    ...

    public LifespanVm LifespanVm { get { return GetSatelliteVm<LifespanVm>(); } }
    public AvatarVm AvatarVm { get { return GetSatelliteVm<AvatarVm>(); } }
    public TelecomNumberPcmShellVm TelecomNumberPcmShellVm { get { return GetSatelliteVm<TelecomNumberPcmShellVm>(); } }

    ...
}
```

## Usage (subclass that contains several entries of ISatelliteVm)

```
public class PersonDetailVm : PartyDetailVm
{
    ...

    public PersonNameVm PersonNameVm { get { return GetSatelliteVm<PersonNameVm>(); } }
    public HonorificVm HonorificVm { get { return GetSatelliteVm<HonorificVm>(); } }

    // THIS is the problem child I cannot add to the map
   ** public GenderVm GenderVm { get { return GetSatelliteVm<GenderVm>(); } } **

 }
```

## ERROR

> Error  82  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Parties.Presentation.ViewModels.PimDetailVms.PersonDetailVms.GenderVm' to 
>       'Core.Presentation.Wpf.ViewModels.MasterDetailVms.DetailVms.SatelliteVms.ISatelliteVm'

## Edit for Billy

Billy, SatelliteVm is just a base class that implements ISatelliteVm. Person is a subclass of Party and Gender is an enum.

```
public class GenderVm : SatelliteViewModel<Person, Gender>
{
}
```

Changes to GenderVm that seem to solve the problem (not sure why!)

```
 public class GenderVm : SatelliteViewModel<Person, Gender>, ISatelliteVm<Party, object>
{

    Party ISatelliteVm<Party, object>.ParentModel { get { return base.ParentModel; } }

    object ISatelliteVm<Party, object>.Model { get { return base.Model; } }
}
```

Comment: Could you give the code for your `GenderVm` ?

Comment: @billy, see last edit too. Not sure why having GenderVm implement ISatellite<Party, object> works but it seems to

Comment: I think the problem you ran into was that an `enum` is not `object`, therefore `SatelliteVmMap` cannot work for `GenderVm`... `GenderVm<Person, Gender>` cannot implement `ISatelliteVm<TParentModel, object>`...

Comment: @billy. Close enuff but enum is an object of course. They just arent support for covariance, as Vlad pointed out. Cheers

Comment: Well, I guess I could say "enum are not 'reference type'" instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233059.aspx):

> Variance in generic interfaces is supported for reference types only. Value types do not support variance. For example, `IEnumerable<int>` cannot be implicitly converted to `IEnumerable<object>`, because integers are represented by a value type.

This must address your issue.

Maybe you should change `Gender` to be a class?

Comment: yeah that is what it is, and I didn't know that! I thought of making a class but having GenderVm implement ISatellite<TParentModel, object> also gets it to work (thx to billy). That is a bit ugly but better than making a do nothing class. Cheers

Comment: @Berryl: yeah, implementing `ISatellite<TParentModel, object>` would work as well. I would personally anyway try to make `Gender` a class, and add a bunch of useful methods to it -- but any way that works is good :)